# Call function from another browser tab with window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

I need call function from another tab. I using for this

```
var str = "javascript:FunctionName('" + param1 + "', '" + param2 + "')";
window.open(str, "WindowsName");
```

Where

```
param2 = "\\\message";
```

But in the FunctionName i receiving

```
param2 = "message";
```

I tried use escape(), unescape() function. But this is din't help me. How can i receive param2 = "\\message" in FunctionName?

Comment: Remember, since '\' is an escape character, you're going to have to need two backslashes for every one, so 'param2 = "\\\\message"'

Answer (score 2):

You should use `JSON.stringify()` instead of manually stringifying them.

```
var str = "javascript:FunctionName(" + JSON.stringify(param1) + ", " + JSON.stringify(param2) + ")";
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem was, but this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the function to window and use `window.opener` to access on the next page.

```
var fn = FunctionName;

var myWin = window;
myWin.fn = fn; //new property on window
myWin.open();

//on new tab
myWin.opener.fn();
```